# ServiceStack RedisMqServer retry interval

Tags: servicestack, redismqserver

How do I set the retry interval of the `ServiceStack` `RedisMqServer`?

I notice there is a property named `KeepAliveRetryAfterMs`, I set this to 10 seconds, will this negatively affect the mq in anyway?

Also, is it possible to have increasingly longer retry intervals? Lets say first retry is 5 seconds, second retry is 1 minute, third retry is 1 hour, and fourth retry is 1 day, etc?